# Microsoft teams error: No internet connection on app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have downloaded and removed the Teams laptop app more then I can count; I can log in via a web browser, but not on the Teams app (my connection is working), receiving error:

```
We couldn't connect to the internet, please check your connection.
```

How do I troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: Have you ever used a "Windows 10 privacy fix" app / script / guide before? Some of those are overly aggressive in that they block (usually using the built-in Windows Firewall) Microsoft domains that are also used by other Microsoft services. Also, make sure that Microsoft's NCSI (Network Connection Status Indicator) is working properly, since some apps rely on that to detect whether you're connected to the Internet or not.

Answer (score 1):

Clear Teams cache (% appdata% \ Microsoft \ team) - delete the contents of this directory, the data will be restored when you roll again

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps and try:

1. Fully exit the Microsoft Teams' desktop client. To do this, either
   right-click Teams from the Icon Tray and select ‘Quit’, or run Task
   Manager and fully kill the process.
2. Go to File Explorer, delete any of the files in the following
   locations:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\teams\application cache\cache
%AppData%\Microsoft\teams\blob_storage
%AppData%\Microsoft\teams\databases
%AppData%\Microsoft\teams\cache
%AppData%\Microsoft\teams\gpucache
%AppData%\Microsoft\teams\Indexeddb
%AppData%\Microsoft\teams\Local Storage
%AppData%\Microsoft\teams\tmp
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data
```

3. Go to IE option and remove the following two caches:

```
Internet Explorer Temporary Internet Files
Internet Explorer Cookies
```

Please tell if you are able to login to Teams web app via https://teams.microsoft.com

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is the type of answer you often see on MS forums. "Try this and this and this and see if anything works." You say "delete any of these files" and list a bunch of locations. Firstly, that's a bit extreme and may have side-effects that you're not pointing out. Secondly, what if someone uses a browser other than Chrome or (eww) IE?